# VBA: How to Show File Path in Userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have a input textbox for my userform. The user is supposed to double click the input textbox and choose a ppm file to insert into it. How to do you show the file path inside the textbox?

```
fileFilter= "PPM(*.ppm), *.ppm, All File(*.*), *.*"
filename= Application.GetOpenFileName(fileFilter, , "Select your Input File")
myFileName=Dir(filename)
```

Comment: Do u mean how to show a default path?

Comment: `Me.TextBox = myFileName` or `TextBox = filename` or `Me.TextBox = fileName` or if you are using MVC framework - `frm.UpdateTextbox(fileName)`

Comment: @Vityata works great! thank you!

Comment: @WIWWrestling - cool, glad I managed to help. See the link in my answer, it can be a game changer for your coding life. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure, try one of the following:

- `Me.TextBox = myFileName`
- `TextBox = filename`
- `Me.TextBox = fileName`

If you are using [the best practices from the ExStackOverflow tutorial](http://www.riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices)   MVC framework -

- `frm.UpdateTextbox(fileName)`